# .innerText of cell is empty even though there is something

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating an agenda on HTML that is able to merge cells with the same content together, so that this:

[Separated Cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHkjf.png)

becomes this:

[Merged Cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnpWe.png)

Everything seems ok, until:

[On the white cell it stops working, on the red cell it crashes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffzRc.png)

This is crazy, I've never experienced nothing like this. [I'm SURE there is something inside the cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUXQo.png), but when printing the content of that cell [it prints nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCzjj.png).
Obviously, this problem also happens for the [white cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffzRc.png).

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d7r0kage/4/) and here's the code I use to merge cells:

```
function mergeCells(){
    var table = document.getElementById("mainTable");
    for (var col = 1; col < table.rows[1].cells.length; col++) {
        console.log("COL: " + col); //for debugging
        for (var row = 1; row < table.rows.length - 1;) {
            var currentCell = table.rows[row].cells[col];
            console.log("ROW: " + (row + currentCell.rowSpan)); //for debugging
            console.log("CURRENTSPAN: " + currentCell.rowSpan); //for debugging
            console.log("CURRENTTEXT: " + currentCell.innerText); //for debugging
            console.log("NEXTTEXT: " + table.rows[row + currentCell.rowSpan].cells[col].innerText); //for debugging
            while (currentCell.innerText == table.rows[row + currentCell.rowSpan].cells[col].innerText && currentCell.innerText != "") {
                table.rows[row + currentCell.rowSpan].deleteCell(col);
                currentCell.rowSpan++;
            }
            row+=currentCell.rowSpan;
            console.log("                    "); //for debugging
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me, this problem is driving me nuts!

EDIT:
Here's the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1TYL.png) it gives me when it crashes.

Comment: And what line of code lives in your code @ `index.js:274:89`? Is this your while loop?

Comment: @dalelandry `console.log("NEXTTEXT: " + table.rows[row + currentCell.rowSpan].cells[col].innerText);`

And of course yeah, if I remove this line it gives me the same error in the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you that currentCell is eventually null, so you should check for that as the first test of ur while loop.

```
while(currentCell && ...
```

Comment: Yeah but it shouldn't be null, there's something in the cell that the script does not see!

Comment: Sorry, after revisiting the error image u left, i see the issue is likely 
`table.rows[row + currentCell.rowSpan].cells[col]` It would be easier to debug if you can put it in a codepen or fiddle so we can see the rest of the table elements.

Comment: There you go, added to the question.

Comment: One obstacle that you had to overcome is the fact that some of the cells already had rowspan set for them.  I decided the easiest way to do that was to simply start by removing any existing rowspan.  Basically do the opposite of the intended end result.  Once the table is in it's expanded form you can merge. Here is a codepen with the code [https://codepen.io/pen?template=OJBoOEo](https://codepen.io/pen?template=OJBoOEo)